# How do I prevent the repetition of "Hello" in this script file?

Tags: bash

Its suppose to display the output username followed by :Hello but it repeats before moving onto the next username displayed.

SCRIPT:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
tail -n +17 $1| awk -F' ' '{print substr($1,1,1) substr($2,1,1) substr($3,1,1) substr($5,length($5)-4+1,length($5)) ": Hello"  }'
```

What I am aiming for:

```
SAB7448 :Hello

BIC3999 :Hello
```

What the output is:

```
SAB7448 :Hello

 :Hello

BIC3999 :Hello

 :Hello
```

Am I overlooking something? Thank you for your time

(example) **Input file:**

```
OFFICIAL CLASS LIST    SPRING 2032

REGISSTRAR'S OFFICE

SYSTEM ADMIN AND SECURITY  CPSC 327 01


16 STUDENTS ENROLLED IN THIS SECTION

First.Name Middle.Init Last.Name  Soc.Sec.No  Campus.Phone
 
SAFFRON    A           BARR       XXX-XX-XXXX 724/555-7448

BRITANY    I           COSTA      XXX-XX-XXXX 724/555-3999

MARGIE     E           CRUZ       XXX-XX-XXXX 724/555-0290

IVY        M           ELLWOOD    XXX-XX-XXXX 724/555-7468

TYLER      V           FINNEY     XXX-XX-XXXX 724/555-3138

CARLEY     D           FISCHER    XXX-XX-XXXX 724/555-4371

TONYA      Y           GALLOWAY   XXX-XX-XXXX 724/555-5920

ANWEN      K           HAMPTON    XXX-XX-XXXX 724/555-1241

FERN       S           KIRBY      XXX-XX-XXXX 724/555-8804

HENLEY     R           LANG       XXX-XX-XXXX 724/555-8935

RILEY      C           MCCOY      XXX-XX-XXXX 724/555-8189

LOUISA     D           RATLIFF    XXX-XX-XXXX 724/555-1207

SULEMAN    L           SHAW       XXX-XX-XXXX 724/555-3201

SHAUNIE    N           SPENCER    XXX-XX-XXXX 724/555-8218

HARLEN     M           SUTTON     XXX-XX-XXXX 724/555-6613

JACOB      G           WHITLEY    XXX-XX-XXXX 724/555-3489
```

Comment: what does `tail -n +17 $1` generate? does it include blank lines?

Comment: Yes there are several blank lines before the listed data.

Comment: Can you provide the input file fed to the script?

Comment: In the input file you've posted, are the blank lines part of the file, or is that something you added to get it to format correctly?

Comment: I edited your question, and put the sample input file into a code block.  This shows the file exactly as it is when you test your solution.  Please review my edit and modify if needed.  What you show must match perfeclty what you use on your computer.  Note also that bash != sh (unless sh is a softlink to bash, which happens on some linuxes.

Comment: If your input file contains blank lines, it is a natural result that you'll have corresponding `:Hello` lines. If you want to skip them, try something like `awk 'NF>1 {print substr($1,1,1) substr($2,1,1) substr($3,1,1) substr($5,length($5)-3) ": Hello"}'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two points.  Your `tail` command must be reviewed, to ensure it will keep the lines you actually want to process.  I assumed that your data file is exactly like that:

**data.txt**

```
OFFICIAL CLASS LIST    SPRING 2032

REGISSTRAR'S OFFICE

SYSTEM ADMIN AND SECURITY  CPSC 327 01


16 STUDENTS ENROLLED IN THIS SECTION

First.Name Middle.Init Last.Name  Soc.Sec.No  Campus.Phone
 
SAFFRON    A           BARR       XXX-XX-XXXX 724/555-7448

BRITANY    I           COSTA      XXX-XX-XXXX 724/555-3999

MARGIE     E           CRUZ       XXX-XX-XXXX 724/555-0290

IVY        M           ELLWOOD    XXX-XX-XXXX 724/555-7468

TYLER      V           FINNEY     XXX-XX-XXXX 724/555-3138

CARLEY     D           FISCHER    XXX-XX-XXXX 724/555-4371

TONYA      Y           GALLOWAY   XXX-XX-XXXX 724/555-5920

ANWEN      K           HAMPTON    XXX-XX-XXXX 724/555-1241

FERN       S           KIRBY      XXX-XX-XXXX 724/555-8804

HENLEY     R           LANG       XXX-XX-XXXX 724/555-8935

RILEY      C           MCCOY      XXX-XX-XXXX 724/555-8189

LOUISA     D           RATLIFF    XXX-XX-XXXX 724/555-1207

SULEMAN    L           SHAW       XXX-XX-XXXX 724/555-3201

SHAUNIE    N           SPENCER    XXX-XX-XXXX 724/555-8218

HARLEN     M           SUTTON     XXX-XX-XXXX 724/555-6613

JACOB      G           WHITLEY    XXX-XX-XXXX 724/555-3489
```

Based on this data, I want to remove the first 11 lines from the processed data.  So I use

```
tail -n +11 data.txt
```

And then I process the file like you did, but added a filter to ensure empty lines are not processes (and therefore avoid  `:Hello` lines):

```
tail -n +11 data.txt | awk -F' ' '!/^$/ { print substr($1,1,1) substr($2,1,1) substr($3,1,1) substr($5,length($5)-4+1,length($5)) ": Hello"  }'
```

What was added is `!/^$/` .

- This matches lines that are not empty.
- `!` do not match the following pattern.
- `//` pattern delimiter.
- `^` line start
- `$` line end
- `^$` starts and ends, with nothing in between == empty line.

**Output**

```
SAB7448: Hello
BIC3999: Hello
MEC0290: Hello
IME7468: Hello
TVF3138: Hello
CDF4371: Hello
TYG5920: Hello
AKH1241: Hello
FSK8804: Hello
HRL8935: Hello
RCM8189: Hello
LDR1207: Hello
SLS3201: Hello
SNS8218: Hello
HMS6613: Hello
JGW3489: Hello
```

Comment: It worked! Picked up some new understanding. Thank you for your time!